# Passport renewal application package questions

Tags: passports, passport-renewals

I'm renewing my U.S. passport via mail and just have a few odds and ends questions prior to shipping it off.

1. The DS-82 form is two pages. Should I staple the 2 pages together, paper clip them together, or just leave them separate when put into the flat rate envelope?
2. On box 10 of the Form DS-82, it asks for both your name as printed on your most recent passport book and then includes boxes for both passport book number and passport card number. I filled out my passport book number (which I'm renewing), but to my knowledge I've never had a passport card. Is it acceptable to leave the passport card number box blank?

Comment: Common sense suggests (1) if they didn't tell you to staple then don't staple, (2) yes leave it blank.  But I'm not sure you'll get an answer backed by anything more authoritative than common sense, unless you take the time to try to contact the State Department (which in my experience is very slow and frustrating).

Comment: If it helps, though, I didn't staple the pages together when I recently renewed my passport, and it went fine.